# How do you keep track of your company computers?

Tags: logging

I wondering what programs or systems everyone is using to keep track of their computers at their company. Spiceworks seems like complete overkill for something as simple as saying Joe is using Laptop #45234

Currently this company has around 70 computers, no general ledger, no list of equipment and half of the computers are field computers that are not part of the domain. For now there is little to no budget until I can stress the importance of it enough to earn it value in the eyes of management.

Comment: This answer is going to depend a lot on the number of computers you are talking about.

Comment: Why does spiceworks seem like overkill? Its specifically aimed at the small to medium sized business, which I'd say fits "70 computers".

Comment: Search ServerFault for "Inventory Management" or "Asset Management" for a bunch of great options.

Comment: @Rob, I dont care for all the extra bells Spiceworks has, I'm looking for something simple and I think I'll just make it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roll Your Own.  I recently took over a small (~350 entries) inventory tracking system in Excel.  What a nightmare!  I've since merged the existing data into a custom access database to track location, configuration, installed software, etc.  I then built a web frontend for the PHBs to view the inventory using ADOdb.

You'll also need to purchase or create some inventory asset tags.  Spend a little time considering the numbering scheme as you'll want it to be useful for the foreseeable future.

These parts will be easy.  Convincing management to implement a compulsory inventory update for your initial data will be more challenging.

Comment: I think that your suggestion might be my best option. I do program in C# and VB so making an ASP.Net Project to track this data is looking more and more like the right thing to do. Thanks Josh.

Answer (score 5):

*Inventory management* should be integrated with the *General Ledger* system. Depending on what GL you're using, there should be a module for inventory.

If, however, you're saying that computer inventory is a *non-asset*, or expensed, then there should be a system for tracking computer/software issues, and there should be an inventory module from that.

It's all about cost-benefit and how your computers are valued. We can give specific recommendations all day long, but what you need to know is

1. your budget,
2. your current system,
3. integration possibilities, and
4. ultimate goal.

**This is more of an internal-process than a process you should be asking a Q&A site**. It's just not cut-and-dry. *I speak from an accounting/auditing background, not an IT background.*

If you have a small company that doesn't need some complex system, then have an IT clerk keep an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

I, along with a few other colleagues from Cisco, are presently embarking on building an open source cmdb tool that will allow you to do this...for free.
It's our way of "giving back".

The project is just in the starting phase of planning what features and functionality will be needed. If any of you are interested, we would love to get your feedback on what the software should provide.

Note that although we work @ Cisco, this will be a completely free tool not associated with Cisco Systems, Inc. We're just doing it for "fun" :-)

Comment: Anything to link? I'd help test this.

Comment: We have a code repo set up with just some very basic beginning code. Nowhere near the test stage yet. If you want to be on the dev team or have input as to how the front end should look, or any back end processes, please let me know.

Comment: I'd be happy to help with anything, what's the best way to contact you for additional details?

Comment: Clayton, please count me in, I would love to provide some ideas (though I don't program) but i can help test it out and can give some ideas - if that is ok ? Thanks !! Community needs this !!

Answer (score 2):

We use [RackTables](http://www.racktables.org/) to manage where systems are, what their hardware specs are, warranty information, IP address space, and so on.  It's fairly extensible with regard to what kind of data you can stuff in it and track.  Reporting is a little light.

Comment: An awesome project, but I think it's more for data centers than my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

If SpiceWorks is overkill, this might be too - but I thought I'd put it up anyway...

Take a look at [Open-AudIT](http://www.open-audit.org). It's easy to use and you can associate a user with a PC.

Caveat - I'm the author.

[image: Sample Report]

Comment: I'm wondering why there are so many down votes?

Comment: No idea - it's a valid answer for the question... Yet the "Roll Your Own" response gets voted up. WTH? There has been a LOT of work put into Open-AudIT so you don't need to go through that. You can even just grab the audit script (VBscript) - it outputs valid XML, and use that. Sigh.

Comment: Keep on keepin' on Mark. The world needs people like you to make things free and awesome.

Comment: The down votes are because SF doesn't like ads or answers that looks like an ad. http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3330/are-answers-from-a-vendor-allowed